# Equivalency Statement

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $X$ and $S$ a non-empty subset of $A$. I am trying to prove a bunch of equivalency statements for this problem but I am stuck in showing that if $S$ is dense in $A$ then $cl(S)=cl(A)$. I have shown that $cl(S)$ is a subset of $cl(A) $but i am stuck going the other way. Suggestions?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "dense". The very property that you're trying to prove is a reasonable definition of "dense", but obviously not the one you're using. So give us the one you're using.

Comment: Dense as in if S is dense in A then for every element in A there is a sequence in S that converges to it.

Answer (score 2):

By (one of many) definition, $S$ is dense in $A$ if $\operatorname{cl}(S) = A$. In particular, since the closure of a set is obviously closed, it follows that $A$ is closed; i.e. $\operatorname{cl}(A) = A$. It follows that $\operatorname{cl}(S) = \operatorname{cl}(A)$. If your definition differ from mine, try to prove that they are equivalent.

Comment: We have not yet defined what it means to be closed in my class. Any other suggestions as to how to do it without that?

Comment: How would you describe the closure of a set?